# Not update button title when start countdown

Tags: java, vaadin7

In my Vaadin project when click button then I need:

1. Start countdown (10 seconds)
2. Replace button's caption by left seconds (10,9,8 and so on)

I try this:

```
private Button buttonNext, buttonSendSMS;

private void runCountDown() {
        logger.info("countDown_start");
        buttonSendSMS.setEnabled(false);
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            int leftSeconds = 10;

            public void run() {
                leftSeconds--;

                UI.getCurrent().access(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        logger.info("leftSeconds = " + leftSeconds);
                        buttonSendSMS.setCaption(leftSeconds + "");
                    }
                });

                if (leftSeconds < 0) {
                    logger.info("countDown_finish");
                    timer.cancel();
                    buttonSendSMS.setEnabled(true);
                    new MessageService(getWzContext().getLang());
                    buttonSendSMS.setCaption(MessageService.getMessage("resend.sms"));
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
```

When click button here log:

```
 INFO] 12.01.2021 17:35:58.112 [Timer-0] com.myproject.client.ui.wz.SmsCodeStepWz$2$1.run(SmsCodeStepWz.java:202) 
    leftSeconds = 9
INFO] 12.01.2021 17:35:59.111 [Timer-0] com.myproject.client.ui.wz.SmsCodeStepWz$2$1.run(SmsCodeStepWz.java:202) 
    leftSeconds = 8
[INFO] 12.01.2021 17:36:00.110 [Timer-0] com.myproject.client.ui.wz.SmsCodeStepWz$2$1.run(SmsCodeStepWz.java:202) 
    leftSeconds = 7
[INFO] 12.01.2021 17:36:01.110 [Timer-0] com.myproject.client.ui.wz.SmsCodeStepWz$2$1.run(SmsCodeStepWz.java:202) 
    leftSeconds = 6
[INFO] 12.01.2021 17:36:02.111 [Timer-0] com.myproject.client.ui.wz.SmsCodeStepWz$2$1.run(SmsCodeStepWz.java:202) 
    leftSeconds = 5
[INFO] 12.01.2021 17:36:03.110 [Timer-0] com.myproject.client.ui.wz.SmsCodeStepWz$2$1.run(SmsCodeStepWz.java:202) 
    leftSeconds = 4
[INFO] 12.01.2021 17:36:04.110 [Timer-0] com.myproject.client.ui.wz.SmsCodeStepWz$2$1.run(SmsCodeStepWz.java:202) 
    leftSeconds = 3
```

But on Web page replace button's caption to **9**. Nice.

But after one second NOT REPLACE by **8**. And nothing happened. Button's caption is only **9**.

As you can see I try to update button's caption on UI thread but it not help.

Comment: Did you confirm that you have Push properly configured and functioning?

Comment: @TarekOraby No, I'm not confirm

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code with Vaadin version 8.12.0 and it works fine. It sounds like you don't have [Server Push](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html) properly configured. In the simplest case, you need to add `@Push` annotation on your class for your code to work.

**EDIT:**
The following similar example works fine in Vaadin 7.7.17.

```
@Push
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        setContent(layout);

        Button button = new Button("", e -> Notification.show("Hello world"));
        layout.addComponents(button);

        button.setEnabled(false);
        final Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            int leftSeconds = 10;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                leftSeconds--;

                UI.getCurrent().access(() -> button.setCaption(leftSeconds + ""));

                if (leftSeconds < 1) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
                        button.setCaption("Click me");
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                    });
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Comment: I try with @Push but it not  help. Vaadin 7.3.6

Comment: @a_subscriber I updated my answer with the code I used for testing (which is working in v. 7.7.17 as well). I couldn't test with 7.3.6 as I couldn't figure out the structure of the pom.xml. But, if the same example isn't still working in 7.3.6, then some old bug might be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

#### Testing based on question

Based on your question I created a demo application for Vaadin 7.3.6 and tested this use case. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce your issue based on the provided information.

Here are the steps I took

1. Created a new Vaadin 7.3.6 application using the Maven Archetype command

```sh
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application \
   -DarchetypeVersion=7.3.6 \
   -DgroupId=io.github.pgerhard \
   -DartifactId=stackoverflow-65687155 \
   -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT \
   -Dpackaging=war
```

2. Updated the generated UI class with the timer logic. Here is the updated code of my UI class

```java
package io.github.pgerhard;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Push;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

@Push
@Theme("mytheme")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinUI.class, widgetset = "io.github.pgerhard.AppWidgetSet")
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        final Button button = new Button("Start Countdown");
        final Label countDownLabel = new Label("Count Down Running ");
        countDownLabel.setVisible(false);

        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                countDownLabel.setVisible(true);
                layout.addComponent(countDownLabel);
                button.setCaption("10");
                button.setEnabled(false);

                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    int secondsLeft = 10;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.printf("Seconds left: %d%n", secondsLeft);

                        if (secondsLeft < 0) {
                            timer.cancel();
                            UI.getCurrent().access(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button.setCaption("Start Countdown");
                                    countDownLabel.setVisible(false);
                                    button.setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            UI.getCurrent().access(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button.setCaption(String.valueOf(secondsLeft));
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        secondsLeft--;
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);
            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(button);
        layout.addComponent(countDownLabel);
    }

}
```

3. Built the project using `mvn clean install`
4. Started the Jetty server included by the Maven archetype using `mvn jetty:run`

All of my code, details on my OS and Java version are available on Github https://github.com/pgerhard/stackoverflow-65687155

As  [Tarek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11982497/tarek-oraby) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698511/8431247) adding `@Push` enabled the UI to be update from the server side for me.

#### Alternative Causes

Without further details on your exact scenario I can come up with the following reasons why this does not work

1. By default Vaadin 7.3.6 uses `Transport.WEBSOCKET` for Server Push using the `@Push` annotation. This may be being blocked in your deployment, you could try changing to using `Transport.LONG_POLLING`
2. The issue is not related to Vaadin but rather your servlet container

---

Also, while this not related the issue regarding the updating of your buttons caption, I believe the provided code contains another bug. When the count down is finished you are enabling the button again, however you are not accessing the UI in order to this. Thus the update will not be pushed to the client. I believe you should change

```java
if (leftSeconds < 0) {
    logger.info("countDown_finish");
    timer.cancel();
    buttonSendSMS.setEnabled(true);
    new MessageService(getWzContext().getLang());
    buttonSendSMS.setCaption(MessageService.getMessage("resend.sms"));
}
```

to

```java
if (leftSeconds < 0) {
    logger.info("countDown_finish");
    timer.cancel();
    new MessageService(getWzContext().getLang());
    UI.getCurrent().access(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            buttonSendSMS.setEnabled(true);
            buttonSendSMS.setCaption(MessageService.getMessage("resend.sms"));
        }
    });
}
```

Note the call to `UI.getCurrent().access()` and then enabling the button inside this, along with updating the caption.